# Confidence interval for the change in E(y), for simple linear regression

Tags: linear-regression, confidence-interval

**Question.**  Given the data in the table below we want to compute a 95% confidence interval for the change in the expected value of the salary, given decrease in GPA by 0.3.  In other words, we want a 95% CI for $\Delta\mathbb{E}(y)$ given that $\Delta x=-0.3$.

*Attempt at an answer.*  My first thought is that since $\Delta\mathbb{E}(y)=\beta_1\cdot\Delta x$, where $(1.86076,3.48089)$ is a 95% CI for $\beta_1$, then perhaps we could just multiply that by $-0.3$ to obtain $(-1.04427,-0.55823)$.  However, this is just a conjecture and I can't prove it, and moreover it seems suspiciously too easy.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The 95% confidence interval of $\beta_1$ is derived from the fact that $\frac{\hat{\beta}_1-\beta_1}{\sqrt{\frac{\text{MSE}}{\sum(x-\bar{x})^2}}}$ has an approximate student's $T$ distribution with $n-2$ degrees of freedom. This implies $$\begin{eqnarray*}1-\alpha&=&\mathbb{P}\left(t_{1-\alpha/2}<\frac{\hat{\beta_1}-\beta_1}{\sqrt{\frac{\text{MSE}}{\sum(x-\bar{x})^2}}}<t_{\alpha/2}\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$ where $\text{MSE}=\frac{1}{n-2}\sum (y- \hat{y})^2$. Can you use the above relationship to derive your strategy for finding the $95$% confidence interval of $\mathbb{E}(y)=(\Delta x)\beta_1$?

Comment: I meant to write $\Delta \mathbb{E}(y),$ not $\mathbb{E}(y)$

Comment: Note that $\mathbf{E}(y)$ is a _number_ and therefore, a CI for it, makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe you want a $95\%$ CI for $(x + \Delta x) \hat \beta_1$?